# LeetCode 218: The Skyline Problem II

Tags: java, performance, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge

Here I'm posting my Java code for [the skyline problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem/). If you have time and would like to review, please do so, I'd appreciate that.

#### Problem

> A city's skyline is the outer contour of the silhouette formed by all
> the buildings in that city when viewed from a distance. Now suppose
> you are given the locations and height of all the buildings as shown
> on a cityscape photo (Figure A), write a program to output the skyline
> formed by these buildings collectively (Figure B).
>
> Buildings Skyline Contour The geometric information of each building
> is represented by a triplet of integers [Li, Ri, Hi], where Li and Ri
> are the x coordinates of the left and right edge of the ith building,
> respectively, and Hi is its height. It is guaranteed that 0 ≤ Li, Ri ≤
> INT_MAX, 0 < Hi ≤ INT_MAX, and Ri - Li > 0. You may assume all
> buildings are perfect rectangles grounded on an absolutely flat
> surface at height 0.
>
> For instance, the dimensions of all buildings in Figure A are recorded
> as: [ [2 9 10], [3 7 15], [5 12 12], [15 20 10], [19 24 8] ] .
>
> The output is a list of "key points" (red dots in Figure B) in the
> format of [ [x1,y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ... ] that uniquely defines a
> skyline. A key point is the left endpoint of a horizontal line
> segment. Note that the last key point, where the rightmost building
> ends, is merely used to mark the termination of the skyline, and
> always has zero height. Also, the ground in between any two adjacent
> buildings should be considered part of the skyline contour.
>
> For instance, the skyline in Figure B should be represented as:[ [2
> 10], [3 15], [7 12], [12 0], [15 10], [20 8], [24, 0] ].
>
> Notes:
>
> The number of buildings in any input list is guaranteed to be in the
> range [0, 10000]. The input list is already sorted in ascending order
> by the left x position Li. The output list must be sorted by the x
> position. There must be no consecutive horizontal lines of equal
> height in the output skyline. For instance, [...[2 3], [4 5], [7 5],
> [11 5], [12 7]...] is not acceptable; the three lines of height 5
> should be merged into one in the final output as such: [...[2 3], [4
> 5], [12 7], ...]

[image]

[image]

#### Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Collections;


class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> getSkyline(int[][] buildings) {
        List<List<Integer>> heights = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> heightTreeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        List<List<Integer>> contour = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
        int lastHeight = 0;

        for (int[] building : buildings) {
            heights.add(Arrays.asList(building[0], -building[2]));
            heights.add(Arrays.asList(building[1], building[2]));
        }

        Collections.sort(heights, (a, b) -> (
                             a.get(0).intValue() != b.get(0).intValue() ? a.get(0) - b.get(0) : a.get(1) - b.get(1)
                         ));
        heightTreeMap.put(0, 1);

        for (List<Integer> val : heights) {
            int height = val.get(1);

            if (height < 0)
                heightTreeMap.put(-height, -~heightTreeMap.getOrDefault(-height, 0));

            else if (heightTreeMap.getOrDefault(height, 0) > 1)
                heightTreeMap.put(height, heightTreeMap.get(height) - 1);

            else
                heightTreeMap.remove(height);

            if (heightTreeMap.lastKey() != lastHeight) {
                lastHeight = heightTreeMap.lastKey();
                contour.add(Arrays.asList(val.get(0), lastHeight));
            }
        }

        return contour;
    }
}
```

On LeetCode, we are only allowed to change the argument names and brute force algorithms are discouraged, usually fail with TLE (Time Limit Error) or MLE (Memory Limit Error).

#### [LeetCode's Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem/solution/) - Not for review

```
class Solution {
  /**
   *  Divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve skyline problem, 
   *  which is similar with the merge sort algorithm.
   */
  public List<List<Integer>> getSkyline(int[][] buildings) {
    int n = buildings.length;
    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    // The base cases 
    if (n == 0) return output;
    if (n == 1) {
      int xStart = buildings[0][0];
      int xEnd = buildings[0][1];
      int y = buildings[0][2];

      output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(xStart); add(y); }});
      output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(xEnd); add(0); }});
      // output.add(new int[]{xStart, y});
      // output.add(new int[]{xEnd, 0});
      return output;
    }

    // If there is more than one building, 
    // recursively divide the input into two subproblems.
    List<List<Integer>> leftSkyline, rightSkyline;
    leftSkyline = getSkyline(Arrays.copyOfRange(buildings, 0, n / 2));
    rightSkyline = getSkyline(Arrays.copyOfRange(buildings, n / 2, n));

    // Merge the results of subproblem together.
    return mergeSkylines(leftSkyline, rightSkyline);
  }

  /**
   *  Merge two skylines together.
   */
  public List<List<Integer>> mergeSkylines(List<List<Integer>> left, List<List<Integer>> right) {
    int nL = left.size(), nR = right.size();
    int pL = 0, pR = 0;
    int currY = 0, leftY = 0, rightY = 0;
    int x, maxY;
    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    // while we're in the region where both skylines are present
    while ((pL < nL) && (pR < nR)) {
      List<Integer> pointL = left.get(pL);
      List<Integer> pointR = right.get(pR);
      // pick up the smallest x
      if (pointL.get(0) < pointR.get(0)) {
        x = pointL.get(0);
        leftY = pointL.get(1);
        pL++;
      }
      else {
        x = pointR.get(0);
        rightY = pointR.get(1);
        pR++;
      }
      // max height (i.e. y) between both skylines
      maxY = Math.max(leftY, rightY);
      // update output if there is a skyline change
      if (currY != maxY) {
        updateOutput(output, x, maxY);
        currY = maxY;
      }
    }

    // there is only left skyline
    appendSkyline(output, left, pL, nL, currY);

    // there is only right skyline
    appendSkyline(output, right, pR, nR, currY);

    return output;
  }

  /**
   * Update the final output with the new element.
   */
  public void updateOutput(List<List<Integer>> output, int x, int y) {
    // if skyline change is not vertical - 
    // add the new point
    if (output.isEmpty() || output.get(output.size() - 1).get(0) != x)
      output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(x); add(y); }});
      // if skyline change is vertical - 
      // update the last point
    else {
      output.get(output.size() - 1).set(1, y);
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Append the rest of the skyline elements with indice (p, n)
   *  to the final output.
   */
  public void appendSkyline(List<List<Integer>> output, List<List<Integer>> skyline,
                            int p, int n, int currY) {
    while (p < n) {
      List<Integer> point = skyline.get(p);
      int x = point.get(0);
      int y = point.get(1);
      p++;

      // update output
      // if there is a skyline change
      if (currY != y) {
        updateOutput(output, x, y);
        currY = y;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference

[218. The Skyline Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem/)

[218. The Skyline Problem (Discussion)](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

[Additional Details](https://briangordon.github.io/2014/08/the-skyline-problem.html)

Comment: Your link for the problem is incorrect. https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem

Comment: Your solution is O(nlogn). A more efficient algorithm would avoid the sorting.